meaning of to drive out between trains
I am reading Edith Wharton's famous 'Afterward' (1910).
Which is a struggle for me since many of her sentences and words are beyond my understanding. (English is not my native language)
Anyway, today's question is as below:

She went first to the kitchen-garden, where the espaliered pear-trees drew complicated patterns on the walls, and pigeons were fluttering and preening about the silvery-slated roof of their cot. There was something wrong about the piping of the hothouse, and she was expecting an authority from Dorchester, who was to drive out between trains and make a diagnosis of the boiler.

I don't understand 'to drive out between trains' in the above.
It seems not an idiom.
My wild guess is to use a car by himself to get to the protagonist's house and time-wise it is between train hours. (due to his available time or whatever reason)

I think your guess is probably correct, except that in 1910 drive could have meant 'be driven in a car' or even 'be driven in a horse-drawn vehicle' (car ownership being uncommon in those days). It might also mean that he would be driven to the house from the local station and  taken back in time to catch the next train back.

Kate is almost certainly right (in particular about about slotting in the visit, drives and labour time, between the forward and return trains). And you are correct about 'doing something between trains' not being idiomatic. Far more usual would be something like '.. and still be/was able to make it back to the station in time for the return train'./// Nothing to do with the expected visitor being plumb loco.

Like to do something (grab lunch, catch a show, attend a meeting, etc.) between flights, except it was trains not planes, I'd guess, as mentioned.

@KateBunting that should be an answer.

@Greybeard It's not about a standard usage; possibly belongs on Literature (as a 'comprehension' request).

@EdwinAshworth I must say I am surprised. You must have heard the old Advert "The snack you can eat between meals" or "I am between wives at the moment.", etc. "To drive out" is also clear enough.

@Greybeard  Google ngrams for 'eat between meals'; 'drive out between trains' (and all the latter are the given quote). 'Eat between meqls' obviously means eat something between lunch and tea, say. But 'drive out between trains' could mean 'drive out making sure you don't get held up at the level crossing' .... One's left making an educated guess. Such interpretation belongs on a different site.

Between trains is not an idiom, but the consensus seems to be that this is what Edith Wharton meant: The expert was to arrive by train at the local station, be driven to the house in a taxi or horse-drawn vehicle, and after inspecting the boiler be taken back in time for the next train back to Dorchester.
Before the Beeching cuts of the 1960s, there were many small rural stations in Britain. (Though Wharton was American, this story seems to be set in England.)
